# How can I eliminate false states of my monitored region in the location manager's didDetermineState method?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, geofencing

I am using

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLCircularRegion *)region
```

to determine if my user is currently in a region without crossing boundaries. The problem I am having is that the state given is

```
CLRegionStateInside
```

even though my location manager's accuracy at the time could be 4,000 meters, which is essentially giving me a "false state" if I am not even close to the boundary let alone inside the region.

So the question is how can one eliminate these false states given by the location manager inside the given method?

I thought about saving the accuracy along with the latitude and longitude and checking them before I check the state of the region. But I thought there has to be a better way. Now I am here at SO looking for input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this earlier and it didn't seem to work, but then I changed the delegate of my location manager and it seems to work now in the didDeterminState method.

```
CLLocation* location = [self.locationManager location];
NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
float accuracy = location.horizontalAccuracy;
NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
CLLocation* regionLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:region.center.latitude longitude:region.center.longitude];
CLLocationDistance distance = [location distanceFromLocation:regionLocation];    

if (state == CLRegionStateInside && abs(howRecent) < 10 && accuracy <= 100 && distance < region.radius)
{
    //Do Something
}
```